# Removing inner objects in mongodb using javascript

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate

I have an object like this

```
{
   "_id" : 1,
   "title" : "abc123",
   "isbn" : {
      "prefix" : "000",
      "group" : "11",
      "publisher" : "2222",
      "title" : "333",
      "checkDigit" : "4"
   },
   "lastName" : "zzz",
   "copiesSold" : 5
}
```

I want the result to be like this.I am trying to remove the inner object. can anybody help me doing it in mongodb.

```
{
   "_id" : 1,
   "title" : "abc123",
    "prefix" : "000",
    "group" : "11",
    "publisher" : "2222",
   "title" : "333",
   "checkDigit" : "4"
   "lastName" : "zzz",
   "copiesSold" : 5
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried project  and group. I tried different ways but could not get any solution

Comment: Really you can just do something like `db.collection.find().map(d => ({ ...(({ isbn, ...rest }) => rest)(d), ...d.isbn  }));` as the simplest code, but there are also approaches for MongoDB as linked. Note in all cases you have "title" in both the top level and the inner object you want to promote, so unless you rename or remove that duplication it will overwrite the parent. You cannot have **two** keys of the same name in an Object. Anyway, the question has been fully answered before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either just `$project` each field individually or use `$replaceRoot`

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $project: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "title" : 1,
    "prefix" : "$isbn.prefix",
    "group" : "$isbn.group",
    "publisher" : "$isbn.publisher",
    "isbntitle" : "$isbn.title",
   "checkDigit" : "$isbn.checkDigit"
   "lastName" : 1,
   "copiesSold" : 1
  }
})
```

or

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $addFields: {"isbn._id": "$_id", "isbn.rTitle": "$title"}
}, {
  $replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$isbn'}
})
```